# (Osh) Omake Error: Unexpected Token: String: {

Tags: c, shell, ubuntu

I am working on an assignment for class, in which we have to build a simple shell interface for a Unix system in C. I am using Ubuntu and when I run the source code in that was provided using this command:

```
osh> cat shell.c
```

I get an error:

```
*** omake error: File /home/cameron/cs426/Project1/shell.c: line 11, characters 20-24
unexpected token: string: {
```

This is my first time using osh, so does anyone have any ideas as to what the issue might be?

Also, here's the code, just in case.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>

#define MAX_LINE 80 /* 80 chars per line, per command */

int main(void)
{
char *args[MAX_LINE/2 + 1];     /* command line (of 80) has max of 40 arguments */
int should_run = 1;

while(should_run){
    printf("osh>");
    fflush(stdout);

    /**
     * After reading user input, the steps are:
     * (1) fork a child process
     * (2) the child process will invoke execvp()
     * (3) if command included &, parent will invoke wait()
     */
}

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Type `which osh`, probably you are not running the `osh` you want

Comment: that returns /usr/bin/osh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this code was intended to be a shell. What you need to do is:

1. Open a terminal that runs a real shell. `osh` is the [OMake](http://omake.metaprl.org/index.html) shell, and is probably not relevant this assignment. The code you gave *prints* "osh", but isn't *the* osh.
2. Compile with `gcc -o shell-that-calls-itself-osh shell.c` The `-o` flag tells `gcc` where to put the compiled binary.
3. Run with `./shell-that-calls-itself-osh` The `./` is to run code in the current directory.

Comment: Thanks. The instructions used `osh` as an illustration, but now that you mention it, I think you're right.